# hide the first slide and exclude it from the pagination count - swiper slider

Tags: javascript, slider, swiper.js

I'm trying to hide every first slide of the swipe slider in product pages, and pagination - that's displaying as "current / total" - should not count this hidden slide for current or total slides number.

{$add_img} is dynamic variable and number of images per product varies.
Most importantly, 'loop:true' should work normally left and right.
With my code below, pagination seems to work fine but looping only works backward(to left).
+looping works well when I remove 'first-slide: display:none;'.
I think hiding first slide with css messes up looping. But cannot figure out other way.
help me how I can resolve this

```js
var productGallery = new Swiper('.product-gallery', {
  loop: true,
  loopedSlides: 1,
  loopFillGroupWithBlank: true,
  autoplay:false,

  slidesPerView: 2,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  // init: false,

  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next-detail',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev-detail',
  },

    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination-detail',
        type: 'custom', // Use custom pagination rendering
        renderCustom: function (swiper, current, total) {
            var currentSlide = current;
            if (swiper.activeIndex === 0) {
                currentSlide = total - 1; // Adjust for the hidden slide
            } else if (swiper.activeIndex === total + 1) {
                currentSlide = 1;
            }
            return currentSlide + ' / ' + (total - 1);
        }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.swiper-container-detail .first-slide {display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="swiper-container-detail product-gallery">
                <ul class="swiper-wrapper" module="product_addimage">
                      <li class="swiper-slide first-slide">{$add_img}</li>
                      <li class="swiper-slide">{$add_img}</li>
                      <li class="swiper-slide">{$add_img}</li>
                 </ul>

                <div class="swiper-pagination-detail"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next-detail"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-prev-detail"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the removeSlide() function?

https://embed.plnkr.co/VuwLi0/